# How can I use sed (or bash / perl / awk) to pull out a substring and write it to a new column?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a string in a csv file (a URL) that looks similar to this:

```
https://www.website.com?utm_campaign=blahblahblah&blahblah?SUBSTRING?moreblahblahblahs
```

I want to pull out the substring that's between the second and third question marks and write it to a new column.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ed - I want to append a new column at the end of the same file it's extracting the substring from and write the substring value into that new column.

Comment: Edit your question to do the following 2 things: 1) Explain what `write it to a new column` means and 2) Post a few more lines of sample input (includes cases you think will be hard to deal with) and the associated expected output. I suspect when you say in your comment `append a new column at the end of the same file` you really mean `append a new column to the end of each line` but idk maybe you really do want to add one column at the end of the file, whatever that means,

Comment: That's a strange-looking URL! It would be clearer if you showed the real data. Are there really question marks in the query like that? Are they supposed to delimit another query field, as they're supposed to be ampersands `&`

Comment: Hey Borodin - I did replace some text in the URL with the "?" so that I would have a delimiter.  The URL looks more like this:

https://www.website.com?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={ifsearch:s}{?443OZgNf?}_pcrid_{creative}_pkw_{keyword}_pmt_{matchtype}_&utm_term={keyword}&network={network}&position={adposition}&devicetype={device}

So I'm looking to pull out "443OZgNf" and write it to a new column.

Comment: @KatieF Your best bet would be to find a module that can parse the arguments to the query for you. It is a really bad idea to change `&` to `?` -- the string is already delimited by `&`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425393/perl-parse-url-to-get-the-value-using

Comment: It wasn't delimited by "&" it was delimited by other characters, which is why I did a find and replace so that I would have a common delimiter.  I've just written a ruby script as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the query string using the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module. Then extracting your target substring will be much easier. And perhaps more importantly, more stable.

**Example:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;

my $q = 'https://www.website.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={ifsearch:??s}{?443OZgNf?}_pcrid_{creative}_pkw_{keyword}_pmt_{matchtype}_&utm_term={keyword}??&network={network}&position={adposition}&devicetype={device}';
my $uri = URI->new($q);
my %query = $uri->query_form;
my ($str) = $query{utm_campaign} =~ /{\?([^?]+)\?}/;
print $str;
```

**Output:**

```
443OZgNf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression (Perl flavour):

```
s/^.*?\?.*?\?(.*?)\?.*$/$1/
```

for example:

```
$ echo 'https://www.website.com?utm_campaign=blahblahblah&blahblah?SUBSTRING?moreblahblahblahs' | perl -lpe 's/^.*?\?.*?\?(.*?)\?.*$/$1/'
SUBSTRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained what "write a new column" means but here is how you can *pull out "443OZgNf"*.

First, as a shorthand, let's define variables for your two long urls:

```
$ url='https://www.website.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={ifsearch:‌​s}{?443OZgNf?}_pcrid_{creative}_pkw_{keyword}_pmt_{matchtype}_&utm_term={keyword}‌​&network={network}&position={adposition}&devicetype={device}'
$ url2='https://www.website.com?utm_campaign=blahblahblah&blahblah?SUBSTRING?moreblahblahblahs'
```

#### Using awk

With awk, we can define `?` as the field separator and then print the third field:

```
$ echo "$url" | awk -F'?' '{print $3}'
443OZgNf
$ echo "$url2" | awk -F'?' '{print $3}'
SUBSTRING
```

`-F'?'` changes the field separator to a question mark.  `print $3` prints the third field

#### Using sed

```
$ echo "$url" | sed -r 's/([^?]*[?]){2}([^?]*)[?].*/\2/'
443OZgNf
$ echo "$url2" | sed -r 's/([^?]*[?]){2}([^?]*)[?].*/\2/'
SUBSTRING
```

Here, `([^?]*[?]){2}` matches all the text up to the first two question marks.  `([^?]*)` matches all the text between the second and third `?` and saves the text in group 2.  `[?].*` matches the third question mark and all after it.

#### Using tr and sed

```
$ echo "$url" | tr '?' '\n' | sed -n '3p'
443OZgNf
$ echo "$url2" | tr '?' '\n' | sed -n '3p'
SUBSTRING
```

Answer (score 0):

In native bash, assuming that the URL is in the third column of the file, and that we don't need to deal with columns containing literal `,`s in their data:

```
while IFS=, read first second url rest; do
    url_piece=${url#*"?"*"?"}    # trim everything up to the second "?"
    url_piece=${url_piece%%"?"*} # trim everything after the first "?" in what's left

    # print variables with commas after them...
    printf -v out '%s,' "$first" "$second" "$url" "$rest" "$url_piece"
    # ...and print to stdout without the last comma.
    printf '%s\n' "${out%,}"
done <in.csv >out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly that you want to pull the text from between the 2nd and 3rd `?` and append that to the end of the string, then a short script will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=${1:-/dev/stdin}

while read -r line; do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$line" $(sed -e 's/^.*[?].*[?]\(.*\)[?].*$/\1/' <<<"$line")
done <"$infile"
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parseurl.sh url.txt
https://www.website.com?utm_campaign=blahblahblah&blahblah?SUBSTRING?moreblahblahblahs SUBSTRING
```

If I didn't understand correctly, then let me know and I'll rework it.