# How to use perl to extract text between and look ahead and a look behind string without applying it twice?

Tags: regex, macos, perl, uri

I currently have a string:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/j2903r293rj092j3r20/view?usp=sharing
```

I would like to extract `j2903r293rj092j3r20` from. I am using a standard perl installation in Mac OS. I have

```
URL="https://drive.google.com/file/d/j2903r293rj092j3r20/view?usp=sharing"
echo $URL | perl -pe 's/https\:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\///g' | perl -pe 's/\/view\?usp=sharing//g'
```

where I apply perl to the front and back. Is there a way to do this in one step instead? thanks

Comment: Maybe `perl -pe 's/.*\/([^\/]+)\/.*/$1/' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/84UqHI).

Comment: Maybe this should be solved with a proper parser https://stackoverflow.com/q/12425393/725418

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse a URL. This is a solved problem. Use the URI module that comes with Perl.

Comment: Perhaps something of this kind `echo 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/j2903r293rj092j3r20/view?usp=sharing' | perl -ne '@parts = split '/' ; print $parts[-2]'` -- output `j2903r293rj092j3r20`

Comment: @PolarBear `perl -F/ -lane'print $F[-2]'` is even shorter. But I think it is still better to use a parser.

Comment: @AndyLester: *the URI module that comes with Perl* As far as I can see, the URI module has never been part of the core Perl distribution.

Comment: @DaveCross You are correct. My mistake. Still, it's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with [macos](/questions/tagged/macos), I guess there is nothing wrong with a simple `sed` command like

```
echo "$s" | sed -n 's,.*/d/\([^/]*\).*,\1,p'
```

Match all up to and including `/d/`, capture the next characters until the first `/` or end of string and then match the rest. Replace with the contents of the first group and only print that value.

Answer (score 4):

When parsing URLs you are probably better off using a proper parser, such as [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new("https://drive.google.com/file/d/j2903r293rj092j3r20/view?usp=sharing");
my @path = $uri->path_segments;
print $path[-2];
```

This prints:

```
j2903r293rj092j3r20
```

I suppose if you need this in a one-liner it would be something like:

```
perl -MURI -lne'$u = URI->new($_); print (( $u->path_segments )[-2])'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

Firstly, using the substitution operator (`s/.../.../`) here is the wrong tool. You can use the match operator (`m/.../`) to just extract the bit of the string that you want.

```
echo $URL | perl -pe 'm/https\:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/(\w+)/ and $_ = $1'
```

Here, we're using "capturing parentheses" to copy the string of "word characters" (alphanumerics and the underscore) that follows the `/d/` in the URL into the variable `$1`. We then copy that into `$_` as that's the variable that `-p` will automatically print.

But we can do better than that. Both `s/.../.../` and `m/.../` allow us to change our delimiters, so that we don't have to escape all of those slashes.

```
echo $URL | perl -pe 'm[https://drive.google.com/file/d/(\w+)] and $_ = $1'
```

We can use `print` directly to remove the slightly confusing variable assignment at the end.

```
echo $URL | perl -ne 'print m[https://drive.google.com/file/d/(\w+)]'
```

And, if we know that our input data is always going to look like the current example, there's really no need to include so much of the URL.

```
echo $URL | perl -ne 'print m[/d/(\w+)]'
```

**Update:** You've got a comment suggesting that you use the [URI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) to parse your string. I'm not convinced that's particularly useful as the module will give you the path part of your URL and you still need to extract the correct part of the path. But, for completeness, here's an example using that module:

```
echo $URL | perl -MURI -ne 'print +(URI->new($_)->path_segments)[3]'
```

We create a URI object from our input and immediately call its `path_segments()` method to get the segments of the path. We print the fourth element of the list that is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put the two pieces comma separated in one perl -pe command:

```
echo $URL | perl -pe 's/https\:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\///g','s/\/view\?usp=sharing//g'
```

Comment: While comma separated list does work, semi-colon is a more standard style, less likely to confuse people.